# AWS CloudFormation condition to only execute when running on the master org (root) account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

All,

I am creating a CloudFormation template.  I would like to conditionally add an IAM policy only if the template is being run in the root organization's master account.

I searched around but wasn't able to find an example.

This is what I am doing now.  I am just asking if the template should include the policy during creation.

```xml
"Parameters": {
    "IncludeOrganizationPolicy": {
        "Description": "Only set to true for the root org",
        "Type": "String",
        "Default": "false",
        "AllowedValues": [
            "true",
            "false"
        ]
    },
}
```

Ideally, I'd like to do this without having to ask for an input parameter.  Something like shown below, but where `AWS::AccountId` is the master root account.

```
"Conditions": {
    "CreateSPOrganizationPolicy": {
        "Fn::Equals": [
            {
                "Ref": "AWS::AccountId"
            },
            "<the root account id>"
        ]
    }
}
```

Also, I am unable to hard-code the root account id.  These scripts are going to be given to customers to run in their AWS environment.

Thanks!

Pink

Comment: `CreateSPOrganizationPolicy` looks like it should work as long as you hardcode the root account id there. Are you trying to dynamically figure out the root account id?

Comment: @kichik Yes.  This template can be applied to any number of accounts but I want to know if it is being run on the master org account at runtime.

Comment: But do you have more than one master org account? Because if not, just put the number of the master org account there and you should be good.

Comment: @kichik I know.  This is my bad.  I don't think I was clear enough, but these are cloud formation scripts that will be given to customers to run in their environment.  So, obviously, I won't know their root account id.  I've updated my question to clarify this.

Comment: Then you might be able to use a custom resource that queries that information using boto3 [`describe_organization()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/organizations.html#Organizations.Client.describe_organization) or another method that gives you the right data.

Answer (score 4):

This doesn't answer the question, but this question came up on a related search so I thought I'd post what I did.

I wanted to a condition to be true for a single AWS account, so I could create a resource in a single account only. I didn't want to have to use a parameter as I already have a bunch and then I'd have to run the stackset / template again.

Here's the condition that worked

```
Conditions: 
  Account123Only: !Equals [ !Ref AWS::AccountId, "123123123123"]
```